# I want to purchase a (.IN) domain name with Crazy Domains

Tags: web-hosting, domains

I want to purchase only the domain name with [Crazy Domains](http://www.crazydomains.in/), I already have web hosting. Can any one advise me on whether or not going with Crazy Domain is fruitful or not?

**Issue:** they have an option with internet banking but at the same time they are providing me details of some account in Dubai but it's an Australian company. So I am bit hesitant with sharing my details with it.

Comment: Never heard their name before. I would recommend you to find reliable registrar, EuroDNS, GoDaddy, ENOM, etc.

Comment: "they have an option with internet banking"? - as a method of payment??

Answer (score 1):

If you dont trust them purchase it from godaddy.com and you can host your application from anywhere by changing a-record